# Resetting permssions on an external hard drive with Windows 10

Tags: windows-10, permissions, external-hard-drive

I dinked up user permissions on my external hard drive, I can't seem to get them reset. Any assistance would be appreciated, I have dug around the net and tried a few things but nothing's worked. I have Windows 10 and the security permissions tab doesn't look like it does on the videos I've found.

I need permissions to the hard drive, and the files I guess. My main concern is the hard drive permissions.

Comment: What methods have you tried so far, and what errors or other results did you get?

Comment: Is the drive formatted with NTFS or something else?

Answer (score 2):

You need to take ownership of your hard drive.

There is a "takeown" command, i.e. if your external drive has been recognized as E partition

TAKEOWN /F E:\ /R /D Y

Once you have taken ownership, then you have to set the permissions; for this, you use ICACLS:

ICACLS "e:\" /reset /T

Have a try

Answer (score 0):

Download this take ownership reg at:

https://www.askvg.com/add-take-ownership-option-in-file-folder-context-menu-in-windows-vista/

Once installed, highlight all folders in your C drive, **right click** and click **Take ownership**.

Be aware that doing this will mean you will be able to control files that you are not supposed to, so **DO THIS AT YOUR OWN RISK.**